# Find the value of tanθ

Tags: trigonometry

If it is given that $$2(\secθ)^2\times(\secθ)^4−2(\cscθ)^2+(\cscθ)^4=\frac{15}4$$
find the value of tanθ?

i tried converting all the terms in cosθ.

Comment: Did you mean to write $2 \sec^2\theta \sec^4\theta$? Because that would simply be $2 \sec^6\theta$. If not, please correct it and preferably by using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: yes  you are correct

Answer (score 0):

substitute :
$$1 + \tan^2 \theta = \sec^2 \theta$$ and
$$1 + \frac1 {\tan^2 \theta} = \csc^2 \theta; \theta \ne (2n+1)\pi/2$$